# finding a limit with parameters

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\left[ {{{{{{n^2} + 2n + 1} \over {{{(4{n^2} + 6n + 2)}^{{{2m} \over k}}}}}}^{}}} \right]^{{1 \over {2m}}}}$$

if $2m=k$ that's easy. We divide by $n^2$ and get $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {a_n} = {\left( {{1 \over 4}} \right)^{{1 \over {2m}}}}$
I'm trying to figure out the two other posibilities ($2m<k$ and $2m > k$)

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: For one case, the limit will be $0$ and for the other, it will be $\infty$. Can you figure out why?

Comment: Hint: Law of L'hospital

Comment: @ShuchangZhang I cannot use Law of L'hospital

Comment: Should I take the same action? (dividing by $n^2$)

Comment: @DanielGagnon Why not? Anyway, what method are you expecting to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $2m <k,$ the highest power of $x$ in the denominator $<2,$ (which is the degree of the numerator) in which case,
the limit $\rightarrow \infty.$

If $2m >k,$ the highest power of $x$ in the denominator $>2$ (which is the degree of the numerator) in which case,
the limit $\rightarrow 0.$